How to display hidden inodes in the file picker?
I've a hidden resources directory that I want to access via the file picker in order to utilize the textures inside it. However, per https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/121715#issue-130067, I've been unable to ascertain whether this is even meant to be possible, much less how to perform it.

Since that issue only seems to have been reported around an hour ago it's unlikely that anyone here will have any information about it! There are no Blender developers here and no-one here works for or has any association with the Blender Foundation.

@JohnEason, I'm the reporter, which was why I linked and asked the question. The "Short description of error" section linked should explain. Thanks anyway.

As https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/121715#issue-130067 explains, it's accessible in a preference context menu within the file browser window:



This preference isn't immediately visible when the height of the window collapses it into a hidden section, which is why I didn't notice it.
